# передаю параметр по клику через router.push в другой компонент, но при обновление этого компонента параметры слетают. как быть?

Tags: vue.js

вот обработчик , где передаю параметр

```
onViewClickHandler(id) {
       this.$router.push({ name: 'view', params:{ id }, query:{id:id}}) 
    },
```

вот в этом компоненте принимаю его через пропс

```
data: () => ({
    Country: {},
     
    
  }),
 
  props:{
    id:{
      type: Number,
      required:true,
      
    }
  },
  mounted: function (){
        this.$axios
        .get("/site/view", { params: {id: this.id}})
        .then((response) => {
           console.log(response.data);
          this.Country = response.data;
        });
      },
```

все работает нормально , до момента обновления страницы.
Получается , что я передаю параметр по клику, при обновлении страницы клика не происходит и параметр не передается , как быть? `введите сюда код`

Comment: В объекте роутера у вас такая запись `{ path: '/view/:id' }` ?

Comment: возьмите `id` не из `props`, а из `$route.params`, т.е. `.get("/site/view", { params: {id: this.id}})` замените на `.get("/site/view", { params: {id: this.$route.params.id}})`

Comment: { params: {id: this.$route.params.id}} с эти таже история получилось , если брать из props, помогло если взять из query  { params: {id: this.$route.query.id}}

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно хранить передаваемый параметр в самом роуте, а не передавать его в методе, потому что в случае с передачей через `push()` этот параметр будет передан только в случае срабатывания `push()`, чего не происходит при обновлении страницы, следовательно вам необходимо хранить `query` и получать его в самом компоненте из `this.$route.query["свойство"]`.

Использование `query` для хранения данных влияющих на отображение также полезно тем, что при передаче ссылки, содержащей данные текущего отображения пользователь увидит её так же, как и вы.